# Where is Percona's my.cnf file?

Tags: mysql, percona

I cannot find where the setting files `my.cnf` or `my.ini` are. I want to change some aspecte of the configuration.

I'm using Centos 6.

Comment: I know it is marked close - but I have been searching for this answer - can the question be migrated to serverfault?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default my.cnf is not created. You have to create it yourself.
see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/673844)

Answer (score 5):

Percona [does not come with a `my.cnf` file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/673844). You create it yourself, presumably to prevent people from blindly using default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: that's true for mysql, not for percona

Comment: You should try installing percona